# How can I determine the overall size of a force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to determine the dimensions of a D3 force directed graph so that I can adjust the size of the canvas after it has been rendered.

I think I am almost there - I can get the size of a single node but I don't know how to iterate through the nodes to inspect the bounding box of each node (or better, get the overall size of the graph in once go). The resize currently occurs on a button click.

My code is below (As a temporary measure I am just multiplying the size of an individual node by 15 but this should be dynamically adjusted based on the dimensions of the rendered graph):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  circle {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  #resizebutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  #graph {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 200px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="resizebutton">
      <button onclick="resizeGraph()">Resize</button>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:lightgrey" id="graph" height="800px" width="800px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var nodes = [{
      name: "node1"
    },
    {
      name: "node2"
    },
    {
      name: "node3"
    },
    {
      name: "node4"
    },
    {
      name: "node5"
    },
    {
      name: "node6"
    },
    {
      name: "node7"
    },
    {
      name: "node8"
    },
    {
      name: "node9"
    }
  ];

  var links = [{
      source: 0,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 1,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 2,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 3,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 4,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 5,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 6,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 7,
      target: 8
    }
  ];

  var width = 800,
    height = 800;

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })

  var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  function tick() {
    path.attr({
      x1: function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      },
      y1: function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      },
      x2: function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      },
      y2: function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      }
    });
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  }

  function resizeGraph() {
    var bbox = circle.node().getBBox();
    wid = bbox.width * 15;
    hei = bbox.height * 15;
    document.getElementById("graph").style.width = wid + "px";
    document.getElementById("graph").style.height = hei + "px";
    svg.attr("width", wid + "px");
    svg.attr("height", hei + "px");
    force.size([wid, hei]).resume();
  };
</script>
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to Gerardo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51137727/4235784) I actually like your approach using the bounding box. You could easily just keep a reference to the `<g>` which holds the circles and get the bounding box from it. As the group's size and position is inherently determined by its contents, its bounding box is also the bounding box over all the circles within.

The implementation is pretty straightforward:

```
var circles = svg.append("g");             // Keep the reference to the enclosing g
var circle = circles.selectAll("circle")   // Append to that group
```

From there on you can get the overall extent of all your circles by doing:

```
var bbox = circles.node().getBBox();
```

Borrowing from Gerardo's implementation and inserting above code results in the following working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  circle {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  #resizebutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  #graph {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 100px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="resizebutton">
      <button onclick="resizeGraph()">Get size</button>
    </div>
    <div id="graph" height="400px" width="400px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var nodes = [{
      name: "node1"
    },
    {
      name: "node2"
    },
    {
      name: "node3"
    },
    {
      name: "node4"
    },
    {
      name: "node5"
    },
    {
      name: "node6"
    },
    {
      name: "node7"
    },
    {
      name: "node8"
    },
    {
      name: "node9"
    }
  ];

  var links = [{
      source: 0,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 1,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 2,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 3,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 4,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 5,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 6,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 7,
      target: 8
    }
  ];

  var width = 400,
    height = 400;

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })

  var circles = svg.append("g");
  var circle = circles.selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  function tick() {
    path.attr({
      x1: function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      },
      y1: function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      },
      x2: function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      },
      y2: function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      }
    });
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  }

  function resizeGraph() {
    var bbox = circles.node().getBBox();
    var rect = svg.append("rect")
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr(bbox);
  };
</script>
```

One benefit over Gerardo's approach is the fact that this solution will automatically take care of **all** the calculations, i.e. it will take into account the circles' radii. This comes in handy if the circles are of different sizes, when just knowing their center is not enough.

If you also want the texts to be part of the overall bounding box, just wrap a `<g>` around the circles **and** the texts and use this outer group instead.

Comment: With apologies to @gerardofurtado I am accepting this solution which I prefer because it seems more general, requires 2 lines less code  and takes care of some details implicitly (it is likely that I *will* have circles of different sizes which this will allow for without modification). Many thanks both for the answers though.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever your goals are, you don't need to use the actual DOM element (for instance, with `getBBox()`) to get the size of the force chart, you can use only its data.

In your code, this will give you the four corners of the rectangle that contains the chart:

```
var minX = d3.min(circle.data(), function(d){return d.x});
var minY = d3.min(circle.data(), function(d){return d.y});
var maxX = d3.max(circle.data(), function(d){return d.x});
var maxY = d3.max(circle.data(), function(d){return d.y});
```

Here is a demo based on your code, click <kbd>Get Size</kbd> to paint the container rectangle (to get the accurate rectangle, wait for the simulation to stop before clicking):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  circle {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  
  text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
  #resizebutton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  
  #graph {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 100px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="resizebutton">
      <button onclick="resizeGraph()">Get size</button>
    </div>
    <div id="graph" height="400px" width="400px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var nodes = [{
      name: "node1"
    },
    {
      name: "node2"
    },
    {
      name: "node3"
    },
    {
      name: "node4"
    },
    {
      name: "node5"
    },
    {
      name: "node6"
    },
    {
      name: "node7"
    },
    {
      name: "node8"
    },
    {
      name: "node9"
    }
  ];

  var links = [{
      source: 0,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 1,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 2,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 3,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 4,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 5,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 6,
      target: 8
    },
    {
      source: 7,
      target: 8
    }
  ];

  var width = 400,
    height = 400;

  var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(150)
    .charge(-300)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

  var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var colors = d3.scale.category10();

  var path = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr('class', 'link')
    .attr('stroke', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })

  var circle = svg.append("g").selectAll("circle")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr('class', 'circle')
    .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
      return colors(i);
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  function tick() {
    path.attr({
      x1: function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      },
      y1: function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      },
      x2: function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      },
      y2: function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      }
    });
    circle.attr("transform", transform);
    text.attr("transform", transform);
  }

  function transform(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  }

  function resizeGraph() {
    var minX = d3.min(circle.data(), function(d) {
      return d.x
    });
    var minY = d3.min(circle.data(), function(d) {
      return d.y
    });
    var maxX = d3.max(circle.data(), function(d) {
      return d.x
    });
    var maxY = d3.max(circle.data(), function(d) {
      return d.y
    });
    svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", minX - 8)
      .attr("y", minY - 8)
      .attr("width", maxX - minX + 16)
      .attr("height", maxY - minY + 16)
      .style("stroke", "red")
      .style("fill", "none");
  };
</script>
```